# PyQt:: если QCheckBox нажат массив принимает [0] = 1

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcheckbox

Если `QCheckBox` нажат массив принимает `[0] = 1`,

путаюсь в реализации:

```
ui.checkBox_3.setChecked(True)
m = ['1', '']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `isChecked()`, чтобы узнать, установлен ли флажок.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.cb1_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("cb1_1")
        self.cb1_1.setChecked(True)                       
        self.cb1_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("cb1_2")      

        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.cb1_1)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.cb1_2)

        self.lb1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Проверить CheckBox`s")
        self.pb1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.rbtn_1_state(
                                      self.cb1_1.isChecked(),
                                      self.cb1_2.isChecked()))

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.lb1)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.pb1)

    def rbtn_1_state(self, cb1_1_chk, cb1_2_chk):
        self.lb1.setText("cb1_1-> {}->({}) , cb1_2-> {}->({})"
                         "".format(cb1_1_chk, int(cb1_1_chk), cb1_2_chk, int(cb1_2_chk)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = Window()
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: круто) спасибо)